# Access 97 and SQL Server

Tags: ms-access, odbc, sql-server-2012

I am needing to read data from an Access 97 wrapper database (around old paradox tables) and insert it into SQL Server 2012. So far the easiest way I have found is to write a conduit database in Access 97 which retrieves the access data and inserts it into linked SQL Server tables. Any thoughts on how better to manage this would be appreciated.

I have linked one of SQL Server tables in, but it won't let me insert data. The linked table is called 'students' in the schema 'push', and this is the table I linked to. However, the error I get when I insert data is 'could not find object dbo.students'. The user account that is being used to connect (user called 'push' also) owns the schema 'push' and has default schema 'push' - so I don't know why it is trying to connect to dbo. In the MSysObjects table in Access, the ForeignName of the linked table is set to push.students. When I open the linked table, I can see the correct dataset from push.students. Anyone can help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK it turns out it was my own fault.

For anyone else having a similar (seeming) problem, the cause was that I have a trigger set on push.students that runs a merge (amongst other things) into dbo.students. Obviously the trigger was being execute by the 'push' user, who does **not** have permission to modify dbo.students - hence the fail. Removed the trigger and it is all sorted!

**UPDATE:**
I still needed the trigger, so I've set it to run under a different user - the dbo account which has permissions to do the things that need doing. This avoids the nastiness of giving open-slather permissions to my restricted 'push' account:

```
CREATE TRIGGER <schema_name>.<trigger_name>
    <schema_name>.<table_name> WITH EXECUTE AS <user_name>
```

etc etc. Hope that helps someone!